# How does OrientDB's master-less architecture handle conflicting writes?

Tags: orientdb

I read in the documentation here:

http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Distributed-Architecture.html

That OrientDB has a master-less architecture where replicas can handle both reads and writes. In the case of two clients writing concurrently to two replicas, how does the database handle conflict resolution between the two versions?

For instance in Riak KV they use vector clocks (or dotted version vectors now) to detect conflicts which either get punted to the user to handle the merge, or a default policy can be set in place to pick something like last-write-wins.

I'm wondering how OrientDB handles this.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/distributed/Distributed-Architecture.html#conflict-resolution-policy) is the Conflict resolution strategy used by orientdb.

> In case of an even number of servers or when database are not aligned, OrientDB uses a Conflict Resolution Strategy chain.
>
> This default chain is defined as a global setting (distributed.conflictResolverRepairerChain):
>
> -Ddistributed.conflictResolverRepairerChain=majority,content,version
>
> The Conflict Resolution Strategy implementation are called in chain following the declaration order until a winner is selected. In the default configuration (above):
>
>   is first checked if there is a strict majority for the record in terms of record versions. If the majority exists, the winner is selected
>
>   if no strict majority was found, the record content is analyzed. If the majority is reached by founding a record with different versions but equal content, then that record will be the winner by using the higher version between them
>
>   if no majority has been found with the content, then the higher version wins (supposing an higher version means the most update record)
>   OrientDB Enterprise Edition supports the additional Data Center Conflict Resolution (dc).
>
> At the end of the chain, if no winner is found, the records are untouched and only a manual intervention can decide who is the winner. In this case a WARNING message is displayed in the console with text Auto repair cannot find a winner for record  and the following groups of contents:[records].

Answer (score -1):

Pretty similar to old school dynamo, only they are super lazy about it, essentially they just use hazlecast for a dht with a low hop count, and to keep partial ordering of events,(hazlecast has something similar to version vectors in each entry of their collections, but I think they use a timestamp rather than a logical clock for some reason), then they slap on a sloppy quorum for read repair, in a query the successor / coordinator, gets the highest clock, fetch the value from that peer and applies it to itself and everyone else,  and for writes they just usually needs an n-1 (n is the replication factor), to do a write again it has to do with the logical clock.

Now as an actual DB, apart from the  total lack of effort on the replication, it's pretty excellent, and I have to hand it to them that they make sound technical decisions.

Before you say oh you couldn't do it, I have done it, and I have implemented dynamo's chord variant, riaks plum tree gossip protocol, DVV, and a shit load of CRDTS, mind you mostly from scratch only using RPC frameworks, message passing, or an event loop when I am in C.

Don't call me an old man because I am 20.